# Drop unique constraint by selected columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to delete constraints from two databases and because of that constraints have different names I want to drop them by selected columns. Is it possible?

For example:

1. Table `CAR` has columns `ID, NAME, ENGINE`
2. Table has unique constraint for columns `NAME, ENGINE`
3. On `db1` constraint is called `constraint1122` and on `db2` it is called `aaconstraint`
4. I want to drop those two constraints using the same sql query but I don't want to use constraint names

Comment: Why not use two queries?  Also, what's wrong with using constraint names?  Dropping constraints is hardly an everyday event.

Comment: I don't want to use constraint names because one db is maintained by developers and the second by some other guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
DECLARE
  l_constraint_name varchar2(100);
  l_table_name varchar2(100);
  l_sql varchar2(2000);
BEGIN
  select uc.constraint_name, uc.table_name
    INTO l_constraint_name, l_table_name
    from user_constraints uc
       , user_cons_columns cc1
       , user_cons_columns cc2
   where constraint_type = 'U'
     and cc1.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
     and cc2.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
     and cc1.column_name = 'NAME'
     and cc2.column_name = 'ENGINE'
     and uc.table_name = 'CAR'
  ;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('alter table '|| l_table_name ||' drop constraint ' || l_constraint_name);
  execute immediate 'alter table '|| l_table_name ||' drop constraint ' || l_constraint_name;
end;
```

You have to run it twice, one time for each database. Make sure you are under the use who is owner the `CAR` table